# MYSQL: View statement produces incorrect SUM totals

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables.  A table for product prices, invoiced products, and ordered products.  I am trying to create a view that joins these.  I want to output the product prices with a total of invoiced products and a total of ordered products.

**products_price**

```
id  season_id   product_id  product_price
1   1           1           3.99
2   1           2           6.99
3   1           3           5.99
4   1           4           5.99
....
```

**invoices_products**

```
id  season_id   invoice_id  product_id  piece_qty
1   1           1           1           1600
2   1           2           2           3200
3   1           3           2           200
4   1           4           1           120 
....
```

**orders_products**

```
id  season_id   order_id    product_id  piece_qty
1   1           1           1           160
2   1           2           1           40
3   1           2           2           20
4   1           3           2           10
....
```

---

Here are a few queries from the View statements I've tried so far.

This query gives me everything I want.  The View's output is perfect but the SUM() for the first 2 rows is off. `total_invoice_product` is double for row 1 and 2. `total_order_product`is 4x for row 1 and 3x for row 2.

**Statement 1:**

```
SELECT 
    `t1`.`id` AS `id`,
    `t1`.`season_id` AS `season_id`,
    `t1`.`product_id` AS `product_id`,
    `t1`.`product_piece_price` AS `product_piece_price`,
    SUM(`t2`.`piece_qty`) AS `total_invoice_product`,
    SUM(`t3`.`piece_qty`) AS `total_order_product`
FROM
    ((`products_price` `t1`
    LEFT JOIN `invoices_products` `t2` ON (((`t2`.`product_id` = `t1`.`product_id`)
        AND (`t2`.`season_id` = `t1`.`season_id`))))
    LEFT JOIN `orders_products` `t3` ON (((`t3`.`product_id` = `t1`.`product_id`)
        AND (`t3`.`season_id` = `t1`.`season_id`))))
GROUP BY `t1`.`season_id` , `t1`.`product_id`
```

This query gives me the output that I expect.  Its not the full output I want but its correct for the statement.  The SUM() totals are off on this one as well.

**Statement 2:**

```
SELECT 
    `t1`.`id` AS `id`,
    `t1`.`season_id` AS `season_id`,
    `t1`.`product_id` AS `product_id`,
    `t1`.`product_price` AS `product_price`,
    SUM(`t2`.`piece_qty`) AS `total_invoice_product`,
    SUM(`t3`.`piece_qty`) AS `total_order_product`
FROM
    ((`products_price` `t1`
    LEFT JOIN `invoices_products` `t2` ON ((`t2`.`product_id` = `t1`.`product_id`)))
    LEFT JOIN `orders_products` `t3` ON ((`t3`.`product_id` = `t1`.`product_id`)))
WHERE
    ((`t2`.`season_id` = `t1`.`season_id`)
        AND (`t2`.`product_id` = `t1`.`product_id`))
GROUP BY `t1`.`season_id` , `t1`.`product_id`
```

---

**the output I want**

```
id  season_id   product_id  product_price   total_invoice   total_order
1   1           1           3.99            1720            200
2   1           2           6.99            3400            30
3   1           3           5.99            576 
4   1           4           5.99            800
```

**output received for statement 1**

```
id  season_id   product_id  product_price   total_invoice   total_order
1   1           1           3.99            3440            800
2   1           2           6.99            6800            90
3   1           3           5.99            576 
4   1           4           5.99            800
```

**output received for statement 2**

```
id  season_id   product_id  product_price   total_invoice   total_order
1   1           1           3.99            3440            800
2   1           2           6.99            6800            90
```

I can build a query like below and it works perfect.  I get the exact output I need but this code does not work as a view.  I get this error: **ERROR 1349: View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause SQL Statement**

**Perfect Query** but will not work as a view

```
SELECT 
    products_price.id,
    products_price.season_id,
    products_price.product_id,
    products_price.product_price,
    invoices_grouped.total_invoice_product,
    orders_grouped.total_order_product
FROM
    products_price
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        invoices_products.product_id,
        invoices_products.season_id,
        SUM(invoices_products.piece_qty) AS total_invoice_product
    FROM
        invoices_products
    GROUP BY 
        invoices_products.product_id) AS invoices_grouped 
    ON 
        invoices_grouped.product_id = products_price.product_id
    AND
        invoices_grouped.season_id = products_price.season_id
LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT 
        orders_products.product_id,
        orders_products.season_id,
        SUM(orders_products.piece_qty) AS total_order_product
    FROM
        orders_products
    GROUP BY 
        orders_products.product_id) AS orders_grouped
    ON 
        orders_grouped.product_id = products_price.product_id
    AND
        orders_grouped.season_id = products_price.season_id
```

**What I need**

I've tried several other statements.  They either got worse results or the same.  Can someone help me get Statement 1 working with a proper SUM?

**Edit 1 for a question**

The information that this view provides will be called upon a lot.  The products_price and invcoices_products tables will not be changed that often.  orders_products will be changed a lot.  If 2 views are required, would it be more efficient to use the "Perfect" query above or use 2 views?

**Edit 2 for another query**

Here is another query from my view statement.  This query is part of **Statement 1** shown above.  This query works perfect but it is not complete.  I need the second SUM column.  When you add the second LEFT JOIN it breaks the SUM totals.

```
SELECT 
    `t1`.`id` AS `id`,
    `t1`.`season_id` AS `season_id`,
    `t1`.`product_id` AS `product_id`,
    `t1`.`product_piece_price` AS `product_piece_price`,
    SUM(`t2`.`piece_qty`) AS `total_invoice_product`
FROM
    (`products_price` `t1`
    LEFT JOIN `invoices_products` `t2` ON (((`t2`.`product_id` = `t1`.`product_id`)
        AND (`t2`.`season_id` = `t1`.`season_id`))))
GROUP BY `t1`.`season_id` , `t1`.`product_id`
```

**output**

```
id  season_id   product_id  product_price   total_invoice   
1   1           1           3.99            1720            
2   1           2           6.99            3400            
3   1           3           5.99            576 
4   1           4           5.99            800
```

Comment: Statement 1: MySQL is quite forgiving when it `GROUP`ing columns. `SUM` is  a group function, and you're grouping by _season_id_ and _product_id_ (so they should work out OK) -  your _id_ and _product_piece_price_ though **are not** grouped, and I suspect they are causing your issue. Try commenting them out and see if the `SUM` works out OK.

Comment: I commented those out and it does not fix the problem.  SUM totals did not change.

Comment: Proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) would be nice.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/28653  I included a couple queries that are commented out

Answer (score 0):

Well, MySql has some limitations, so you will need to create 2 views for subqueries and use them:

```
create view viewInvoices
as
select season_id, product_id, sum(piece_qty) pq 
from invoices_products group by season_id, product_id

create view viewOrders
as
select season_id, product_id, sum(piece_qty) pq 
from orders_products group by season_id, product_id

select pp.id, 
       pp.season_id, 
       pp.product_id, 
       pp.product_price, 
       i.pq as total_invoice, 
       o.pq as total_order
from products_price pp

left join viewInvoices as i 
           on pp.season_id = i.season_id and pp.product_id = i.product_id

left join viewOrders as o 
           on pp.season_id = o.season_id and pp.product_id = o.product_id
```

Comment: This statement is similar to the "Perfect" one above.  The problem though... **ERROR 1349: View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause SQL Statement**.  I need a statement that will work in a View.

Comment: Thank you Giorgi.  The information that this view provides will be called upon a lot. If 2 views are required, would it be more efficient to use the "Perfect" query above or use 2 views.

Comment: If the data in the outer view changes more often than the data in the inner view, two views are more efficient, because the index has only to be rebuilt over the outer view so often. Otherwise, the difference should be negligible.

Comment: @Kuriso, I think both versions will produce same executiton plans. If you will add 2 indexes on season and product columns in orders and invoices it would be good. I don't know much about MySql but if covered indexes are supported then you may consider making covered indexes on season, product and pieceqty columns

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
SELECT * from products_price as a left join (select product_id, sum(piece_qty)total_invoices from invoices_products group by product_id) as b on a.product_id=b.product_id left join (select product_id, sum(piece_qty) as total_order from orders_products group by product_id) as c on a.product_id=c.product_id
```

Comment: This query partially works as a standalone statement.  Its similar to the "Perfect" statement I show above.  This query will not work in a view.  It throws an error: **ERROR 1349: View's SELECT contains a subquery in the FROM clause SQL Statement**  The way it looks I need to make 2 different views.